# How to avoid copy when i want to move data from stack to vector?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I have a very-frequently used operation, which need to move data from stack into vector.

let me write a demo code:

```
void handle(const std::vector<std::vector<std::pair<size_t, double>>> & v) {  // this is my handle data function

}

int main() {
  std::stack<std::vector<std::pair<size_t, double>>> data; // this is my data container, it's a stack
  int cnt = 0;
  std::vector<std::vector<std::pair<size_t, double>>> params(3);
  while (cnt++ < 3) {   // assume this handle need 3 data
    const auto & v = data.top();
    params[cnt] = v;  // i think this will involve copy operation
    // and in real scene, i need to keep params in order,
    // so i cant use emplace back, only can use [i]
    data.pop();
  }
  handle(params);
}
```

can you help on this, how can i avoid copy and speed up my code?

Comment: Your code never modifies the source, `data`.  Is it important that `data` remain unmodified?  (Edit - now the code has changed)

Comment: @klaus you mean ```params[cnt] = v;``` will not copy vector element one by one, just move the reference and very fast?

Comment: `params[cnt] = std::move(data.top());` And I don't understand your explanation for why you can't use `emplace_back`, or `push_back`. Either should work just fine here.

Comment: @Klaus The type returned by `data.top()` is `std::vector<std::pair<size_t, double>>` (in fact, lvalue reference thereto) - it **is** the vector, not a pair of `size_t` and `double`. It very much can be moved.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: You are right... forget about, sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This, your code, will create a copy of the vector.

```
const auto & v = data.top();
params[cnt] = v;
```

This will avert the copy, by *moving* the vector out of `data`.

```
auto & v = data.top();
params[cnt] = std::move(v);
```

Both operations are described, as forms (1) and (2), [in cpprefernce](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator%3D).

Comment: I found this two method has same latency. I use gcc -O3, does complier optimize this for me already, or they should have different latency(move will be much faster)?

Comment: I can't see or comment on your latency test, but the `std::move` should be _very fast_ as long as `v` **is not `const`**.

Comment: @TedLyngmo haha, copied from question.